# R: Removing fraction of binary elements in vector

Tags: r, vector, subtraction

Imagine that you have one vector like

```
a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

and then another vector

```
b <- c(0,1,1)
```

How would you remove "b"-vector elements from vector "a"?

The output should look like that:

```
a (0,0,1)
```

Comment: I suspect there's an answer in communications theory.  There's most likely a polynomial based on `b` (similar to checksums and Forward Error Correction polynomials) that can be used to sweep thru `a` very quickly.  Unfortunately, my knowledge in that area is quite limited.

Comment: Mine too .... but it would be great if it inspires anyone

Comment: Just had a thought, would it be easier to subtract when I change both vectors to frequency tables?

Comment: Ok, I think it worked this way:

a <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1)

b <- c(0,1,1)

Then transformed into Frequency tables :

a <- as.data.frame(table(a))
b <- as.data.frame(table(b))

Frequencies subtracted:

a$Freq = a$Freq - b1$Freq

And then back to vector:

a <- rep(a$a, a$Freq)

Does it make sense? Quite a long walk around to get simple thing done....

Thanks for help!

Comment: you don't need the as.data.frame or selections therein but you're on the right track... just noticed your comment, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question:

a naive approach would be

```
test<-gsub(paste(b,collapse="~"),"",paste(a,collapse="~"))
test<-gsub("~~","~",test)
test<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(test,"~")))
```

EDIT:

you could change your method of sampling for example

```
idx <- sample(length(a))
```

if you want to take a sample of size 3

```
a.sample<-a[idx[1:3]]
a.leftover<-a[-idx[1:3]]
```

and in this case `b<-idx[1:3]`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out (cunning idea), however, your solution seems to be working in situations where my "0"s and "1"s are neatly arranged.

When I tried vector b as 

b <- c(1,0,1) 

It doesn't work anymore.

Any other ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: I was expecting that output from "subtracting" c(1,0,1) would be identical to "subtracting" c(0,1,1).

For some reason, when I swapped the order of elements in vector "b", it failed to compute answer.

Reason why I am worried about that is that my vector "b" is random chain of "0"s and "1"s (not arranged).

I want to take random sample from vector "a" to create vector "b" and then take away elements that were sampled from vector "a" for further sampling. It is like sampling without replacement but I want to get many samples with different size.

Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, that will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I originally interpreted like ttmaccer but now that I see your comments there your issue is much simpler.  You just want to reduce the number of items in A by the items in B and order is pretty irrelevant.

```
at <- table(a)
b2 <- c(b, 0, 1) #in case b contains no 1s or 0s
bt <- table(b2) - c(1,1)
abt <- at - bt
rep(0:1, abt)
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks nicer then mine.

Comment: Just realized that this solution doesn't work when vector "b" has got no "0"s or "1"s at all.

Table is then shorter then table made from vector "a" and one cannot subtract these. Any ideas how to bypass that?

Comment: Also try `tabulate`, though you'd have to make it 1's and 2's.